# Is it memory leak in following case in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Is this a memory leak in following scenario in Swift Programming?

```
var string: String = "test-string-1"  //  statement-1

string = "test-string-2" //  statement-2
```

Is it memory leak through execution from statement-1 to statement-2?

OR Do I this way?

```
var string: String? = "test-string-1"

string = nil

string = "test-string-2"
```

Please answer with proper description.

Comment: what makes you think of there would be a leak here? please, give us a proper description first.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do in the second way.
I guess the first scenario is safe enough.

After setting string to `"test-string-2"`, the reference count of the `"test-string-1"` become 0. So, it will be deallocated by ARC.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to even think about a memory leak here, it is something very different from assigning a new value to a variable. It occurs when an instance is unable to be released from memory and is explained at length by [Apple in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), but in brief here is the simplest scenario:

```
class Parent {
    var child:Child?
}

class Child {
     var parent: Parent?
}

var child = Child()
let parent = Parent()

child.parent = parent
parent.child = child // strong reference cycle created
```

A "strong reference cycle" has been created because the parent holds a reference to a child instance, and that same child instance holds a reference to the parent instance that holds a reference to it. The result is that it cannot be determined when to deinitialize either instance. This can be demonstrated by placing the code in a view controller and running it inside an app:

```
import UIKit

class Parent {
    var child:Child?
    deinit {
        print("deinitialized")
    }
}

class Child {
    var parent: Parent?
    deinit {
        print("deinitialized")
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let child = Child()
        let parent = Parent()

        child.parent = parent
        parent.child = child // strong reference cycle created
    }

}
```

Note that there are no console messages to indicate that deinitialization has taken place because it hasn't. Instead the instances both live on forever more. We call this a leak because the instances do not go out of existence but at the same time they are not reachable.

Now change one of the references to weak like so:

```
import UIKit

class Parent {
    var child:Child?
    deinit {
        print("deinitialized")
    }
}

class Child {
    weak var parent: Parent?
    deinit {
        print("deinitialized")
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let child = Child()
        let parent = Parent()

        child.parent = parent
        parent.child = child // strong reference cycle created
    }

}
```

You will see two deinit messages. The parent alone is now responsible for keeping the child "alive", so it can release the child when it goes out of existence automatically via ARC. There is no ambiguity over who owns who, even when an owned instance has a reference to its owner, because it is now weak (rather than strong).